# Reducibility of $2x^{100} +9x^5 −12x^3 +30x+15$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

By Eisenstein's criterion, $2x^{100} +9x^5 −12x^3 +30x+15$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$. But how can we determine if it's also irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: A polynomial with positive degree and irreducible over $\mathbb Z$ is always irreducible over $\mathbb Q$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Gauss Lemma implies that a polynomial $f\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, which is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$, is also irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. The converse need not be true, as the example $f(x)=2x^2+4$ shows. This is *reducible* over the integers, because we can factor it as $2(x^2+2)$ and both $2$ and $x^2+2$ are not units.

Comment: $2x^2+4$ is irreducible over both $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$. That is, we cannot factor it into two non-constant polynomials over either field.

Comment: No, $2x^2+4=2(x^2+2)$ is **not** irreducible over the integers, since $2$ is not a unit in the integers. See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1845542/irreducible-polynomial-over-mathbbq-implies-polynomial-is-irreducible-over).

Answer (score 2):

It should follow directly from Gauss' Lemma.

The second result states that if a non-constant polynomial with integer coefficients is irreducible over the integers, then it is also irreducible if it is considered as a polynomial over the rationals (from wiki).