# Does irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$ imply irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The question is True or False: "If a polynomial $f$ has integer coefficients and is irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$, then it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$."

The solution manual claims this is True but I think that has to be a mistake. $2x^2+2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$ but 2 is not a unit in $\mathbb{Z}$ so $2(x^2+1)$ would be consider a non trivial factorization over $\mathbb{Z}$ right?

Comment: *Reducibility* of a polynomial in this case refers to breaking it down into a product of polynomials of lower degrees.

Comment: similar to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1845542/irreducible-polynomial-over-mathbbq-implies-polynomial-is-irreducible-over)

Comment: It's a bit sad that "Irreducible in the ring $\Bbb Z[x]$" and "Irreducible polynomial over $\Bbb Z$" don't necessarily mean the same thing. But such is life, unfortunately.

Comment: Recall that an element $r$ of a unique factorization domain (UFD) is *irreducible* if and only if the equation $r = st$ implies that $s$ is a unit or $t$ is a unit. But the polynomial $2x^2 + 2 = 2(x^2 + 1)$ is not irreducible in $\mathbb Z[x]$ because neither $2$ nor $x^2 + 1$ is a unit in $\mathbb Z[x].$

Comment: @Arthur Wait, what?

Comment: @Dylan r should be non-zero and a non-unit

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg See the top comment above by Kelvin Lian.